# Changing alphaMap opacity does not update (THREE.JS R76)

Tags: javascript, three.js, opacity, alpha

I have a tunnel with a rotating texture and alpha map. I would like to change the opacity, eventually tweening, of the alpha map.

I start the opacity at 0 and then later go to raise it. However the live view doesn't change while the opacity property does. It is stuck on full opacity in the live view. I tried switching the needsUpdate property of the material to true but it didn't change anything.

Here is the setup...

```
function addTunnel(){
var cylTexture = loader.load("wormhole.jpg"),
    cylAlpha = loader.load("wormholeAlpha2.jpg");
    cylTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    cylTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    cylAlpha.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    cylAlpha.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5000, 5000, 50000, 32, 32, true),
    cylMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        side: THREE.BackSide,
        map: cylTexture,
        alphaMap: cylAlpha,
        transparent: true
    }),
    cyl = new THREE.Mesh(cylGeom, cylMat);

cyl.name = "tunnel";
scene.add(cyl);
scene.getObjectByName("tunnel").position.z= -9000;
rotateObject(scene.getObjectByName("tunnel"), -90, 0, 0);
octree.add(scene.getObjectByName("tunnel"));
tunnel = scene.getObjectByName("tunnel");
tunnel.material.alphaMap.opacity = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PhongMaterial shader uses the pixel value of the alphaMap as the alpha value as seen in the source [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/alphamap_fragment.glsl).
You are not going to be able to tween this without generating the aphaMap dynamically or altering the shader.
It sounds to me like it would probably be better to create your own ShaderMaterial.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/bhbn1sb8/) is an example of a Dr Who time tunnel type shader, it has transparency (change the body background-color)

```
<script id="tunnelVertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    void main( void ) {
      vPosition = position;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <script id="tunnelFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    uniform vec3 color;
    uniform vec3 noiseScale;
    uniform float speed;
    uniform float time;
    uniform float intensity;

    //
    // Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex
    //               noise functions.
    //      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.
    //  Maintainer : ijm
    //     Lastmod : 20110822 (ijm)
    //     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.
    //               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.
    //               https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise
    //

    vec4 mod289(vec4 x) {
      return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0; }

    float mod289(float x) {
      return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0; }

    vec4 permute(vec4 x) {
         return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
    }

    float permute(float x) {
         return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
    }

    vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
    {
      return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
    }

    float taylorInvSqrt(float r)
    {
      return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
    }

    vec4 grad4(float j, vec4 ip)
      {
      const vec4 ones = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      vec4 p,s;

      p.xyz = floor( fract (vec3(j) * ip.xyz) * 7.0) * ip.z - 1.0;
      p.w = 1.5 - dot(abs(p.xyz), ones.xyz);
      s = vec4(lessThan(p, vec4(0.0)));
      p.xyz = p.xyz + (s.xyz*2.0 - 1.0) * s.www;

      return p;
      }

    // (sqrt(5) - 1)/4 = F4, used once below
    #define F4 0.309016994374947451

    float snoise(vec4 v)
      {
      const vec4  C = vec4( 0.138196601125011,  // (5 - sqrt(5))/20  G4
                            0.276393202250021,  // 2 * G4
                            0.414589803375032,  // 3 * G4
                           -0.447213595499958); // -1 + 4 * G4

    // First corner
      vec4 i  = floor(v + dot(v, vec4(F4)) );
      vec4 x0 = v -   i + dot(i, C.xxxx);

    // Other corners

    // Rank sorting originally contributed by Bill Licea-Kane, AMD (formerly ATI)
      vec4 i0;
      vec3 isX = step( x0.yzw, x0.xxx );
      vec3 isYZ = step( x0.zww, x0.yyz );
    //  i0.x = dot( isX, vec3( 1.0 ) );
      i0.x = isX.x + isX.y + isX.z;
      i0.yzw = 1.0 - isX;
    //  i0.y += dot( isYZ.xy, vec2( 1.0 ) );
      i0.y += isYZ.x + isYZ.y;
      i0.zw += 1.0 - isYZ.xy;
      i0.z += isYZ.z;
      i0.w += 1.0 - isYZ.z;

      // i0 now contains the unique values 0,1,2,3 in each channel
      vec4 i3 = clamp( i0, 0.0, 1.0 );
      vec4 i2 = clamp( i0-1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
      vec4 i1 = clamp( i0-2.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

      //  x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxxx
      //  x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxxx
      //  x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxxx
      //  x3 = x0 - i3  + 3.0 * C.xxxx
      //  x4 = x0 - 1.0 + 4.0 * C.xxxx
      vec4 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxxx;
      vec4 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyyy;
      vec4 x3 = x0 - i3 + C.zzzz;
      vec4 x4 = x0 + C.wwww;

    // Permutations
      i = mod289(i);
      float j0 = permute( permute( permute( permute(i.w) + i.z) + i.y) + i.x);
      vec4 j1 = permute( permute( permute( permute (
                 i.w + vec4(i1.w, i2.w, i3.w, 1.0 ))
               + i.z + vec4(i1.z, i2.z, i3.z, 1.0 ))
               + i.y + vec4(i1.y, i2.y, i3.y, 1.0 ))
               + i.x + vec4(i1.x, i2.x, i3.x, 1.0 ));

    // Gradients: 7x7x6 points over a cube, mapped onto a 4-cross polytope
    // 7*7*6 = 294, which is close to the ring size 17*17 = 289.
      vec4 ip = vec4(1.0/294.0, 1.0/49.0, 1.0/7.0, 0.0) ;

      vec4 p0 = grad4(j0,   ip);
      vec4 p1 = grad4(j1.x, ip);
      vec4 p2 = grad4(j1.y, ip);
      vec4 p3 = grad4(j1.z, ip);
      vec4 p4 = grad4(j1.w, ip);

    // Normalise gradients
      vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
      p0 *= norm.x;
      p1 *= norm.y;
      p2 *= norm.z;
      p3 *= norm.w;
      p4 *= taylorInvSqrt(dot(p4,p4));

    // Mix contributions from the five corners
      vec3 m0 = max(0.6 - vec3(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2)), 0.0);
      vec2 m1 = max(0.6 - vec2(dot(x3,x3), dot(x4,x4)            ), 0.0);
      m0 = m0 * m0;
      m1 = m1 * m1;
      return 49.0 * ( dot(m0*m0, vec3( dot( p0, x0 ), dot( p1, x1 ), dot( p2, x2 )))
                   + dot(m1*m1, vec2( dot( p3, x3 ), dot( p4, x4 ) ) ) ) ;

      }

    float turbulence( vec3 p ) {
      float t = -0.5;
      for (float f = 1.0 ; f <= 5.0 ; f++ ){
          float power = pow( 2.0, f );
          t += abs( snoise( vec4( power * p, time )));
      }
      return t / 5.0 * intensity;
    }
    void main() {
      vec3 nPos = vec3(vPosition.x, vPosition.y - (speed * time), vPosition.z);
      float n = turbulence(nPos / (0.0 - noiseScale));
      vec3 finalColor = vec3(color.x * n, color.y * n, color.z * n);
      float finalAlpha = finalColor.x + finalColor.y + finalColor.z;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor, finalAlpha);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Oh no this is terrible news for me. I just started working in 3D...shaders are not easy for me. I have to use a texture for the alpha map...at least that's how I know how to do it. Can the ShaderMaterial use a texture and then I use a uniform to change the opacity somehow. Some clues would really help me plan it out.

Comment: If I change the entire PhongMaterial shader then wouldn't the other objects using shader have their opacity change?

Comment: Okay I'll slog it out and do my best to figure it out. If I get stuck I'll come on back. Thanks 2pha!

Comment: For the tub material, I would probably use a ShaderMaterial with noise like [THIS](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simplex_noise_3d.html)

Comment: Hmm, I might do a tutorial on it. I have been wanting to do something similar for a while.

Comment: Wow that would be awesome!!! I will reply back with a link to show you what it is I am doing.

Comment: http://giddyuppupsf.com/Projects/Music_Visualizer/      the alpha opacity should increase when collision happens. I'll be figuring that out this month.

Comment: Played around a bit today. [Very basic time tunnel shader](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/bhbn1sb8/). But it seem you have yours working anyway :)

Comment: Ha not quite yet! My workaround was to remove the pixels from the texture and then encase it in a black cylinder. Then change the opacity on the black cylinder. This shader though is AWESOME. I very might well use it. thank you so much. I can't believe how much code goes into it.

Comment: So I am curious how someone would apply this as the alpha mask. It looks like this is the main frag shader. Would I have to blend this with the main texture. I think I would have to reverse the color values for it.

Comment: I hadn't finished it. It was not meant to have a texture applied. There is a color uniform that can be changed. I hadn't yet set the alpha values (which would probably combine the RGB values and set that as the alpha)

Comment: Ah I see. I looked around and its surprising to me how something so short and simple in three.js ends up being so long and intricate in a shader. I had played with using a texture as a shader a couple days ago and couldn't figure out how to make the texture rotate and repeat. A rotating and repeating texture combined with a shader (for the  alpha) like the fiddle you linked would be visually compelling. Especially with the bloom shader I have running now :)

Comment: I think something with...glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)... where the first is the texture and the second is the noise pattern.

Comment: I don't understand why you want the texture, I'm trying to generate the noise texture in the shader. When I have completed a decent shader, I will update my answer.

Comment: I feel like It is easier to use a texture because the learning curve for creating  it 100% with a shader is steeper.

Comment: No worries, but you shouldn't need a noise shader if you are using a texture. Just use the alpha channel of the texture

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to change the alpha based on conditions which was the whole start of this haha. I had tried using a texture and a bit of a workaround here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085334/backside-of-outer-geom-not-visible-when-inside-inner-geom-three-js-r76/37095447#37095447   but then I ran into a bit of an issue with changing the opacity of a colored cylinder (black) when inside another cylinder. So now I am a bit in the  middle maybe go with the amazing tunnel shader or maybe stick it out with the texture.